# Get documents that contains specific attributes in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document collection with recipes that looks like this:

```
{
    "title" : "Pie",
    "url" : "pie.png",
    "people" : "4",
    "ingredients" : [
        {
            "amount" : "150",
            "measure" : "g",
            "name" : "Butter"
        },
        {
            "amount" : "200",
            "measure" : "g",
            "name" : "Flour"
        }
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("55acf33223ae282719bdc9b7")
}
```

Im trying to create a query that retrieves all the documents that contains multiple fields, like "butter" and "flour".

I have managed to retrieve documents that contains one field, like the query below:

```
db.recipe.find(
    {"ingredients.name": "Butter"}, 
    {"_id": 1, "ingredients": {"$elemMatch": {"name": "Butter"}}},        
    callback
);
```

I’ve tried using

```
{ 
    $all: [
        { $elemMatch: { name: "Butter" }}, 
        { $elemMatch:{ name: "Flour"}}
    ]
}
```

but I cant get it to work. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
db.recipe.find({ 
    "$and": [
        { "ingredients.name": "Butter" }, 
        { "ingredients.name": "Flour" }
    ]
})
```

---

EDIT(thanks to @BlakesSeven):

The shorter way to write the above is using the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator.

```
db.recipe.find({ "ingredients.name": { "$all": ["Butter", "Flour"] } }
```

Comment: @Apero I know ingredients is an array. did you try my query?

Comment: Wow, that was much more simple than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: @rtc11 It's even more simple than that `db.recipe.find({ "ingredients.name": { "$all": ["Butter", "Flour"] } }` which is the shorter way to write the above.